# Assigning aliases to objects that are imported using `require`

Tags: node.js, import, alias, require

**Situation:** Say I import a module using `require`:

`const my_module = require('./my_module')`

And, I don't want to have to prepend `my_module` to the names of all my imported objects, so I decide to define some shorter, easier-to-write references to them:

```
const fnA = my_module.functionA
const fnB = my_module.functionB
const fnC = my_module.functionC
```

However, you can see how the above is rather clunky -- you need one line per imported object.

**Question:** What is a more concise way to import objects using `require` while also giving them specific names?

Answer (score 0):

You can [assign to new variable names in a destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).

Given `myModule.js`

```
module.exports = {
  functionA: () => console.log("a"),
  functionB: () => console.log("b"),
  functionC: () => console.log("c"),
}
```

You can do this in `main.js`

```
const { functionA: fnA, functionB: fnB, functionC: fnC, } = require("./myModule");

fnA(); // Logs "a"
fnB(); // Logs "b"
fnC(); // Logs "c"
```